# ¿Como puedo Pintar un Objeto QGraphicsItem antes de que se ejecute un time.sleep()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

espero se encuentren bien.
Estoy tratando de hacer una solución paso a paso para un Autómata de Pila en PyQt5 con interfaz gráfica.
La intención es que se vayan pintando los objetos gráficos en la pantalla cada vez que se hace un paso y ejecutar el siguiente paso cuando acabe el anterior y así sucesivamente.

Pero esta solución implica detener el flujo de ejecución del programa para ejecutar un paso y luego esperar a que termine para ejecutar el siguiente, porque de lo contrario se pintarían todos los objetos al mismo tiempo y es por eso que QTimer no me sirve, ya que este no detiene la ejecución del programa.

Pensé entonces en utilizar sleep() de la siguiente forma:

Cuando se active un paso pintar el objeto correspondiente y dormir el programa por el tiempo necesario, luego cuando despierte devolverle el color al objeto y ejecutar el siguiente paso de la misma forma.

El problema es que aunque la instrucción de cambiar el color a un objeto esté antes de la instrucción sleep(), este no le permite cambiar de color y no se ve ningún cambio.

Como el problema está en las instrucciones de pintado, omito todo el autómata porque algo tan simple como hacer click a un objeto y cambiarle el color y luego devolvérselo después de un tiempo se me ha hecho imposible, lo adjunto a continuación.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor,QBrush,QPen
import time

class State(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem):

    def __init__(self,name):
        QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.__init__(self)
        self.color = QColor(40,20,90) #Color original de los objetos

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QtCore.QRectF(0,0,100,100)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        pen = QPen(QtCore.Qt.black)
        pen.setWidth(4)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        brush = QBrush(self.color)
        painter.setBrush(brush)

        painter.drawEllipse(0,0,100,100)
        self.scene().update()

    def activate(self):
        self.color = QColor(90,40,55) #Cambia el color
        self.scene().update() #actualiza la escena
        time.sleep(2) #Pausar el programa por 2 segundos con el objeto pintado (NO FUNCIONA)
        self.color = QColor(40,20,90) #devolverle el color original al objeto

    def mousePressEvent(self,e): #Al clickearlo ejecuta el método activate
        self.activate()
```

Es cierto que para el ejemplo adjuntado se puede solucionar con QTimer, pero esto no me sirve porque necesito hacerlo paso a paso.

¿Es posible ejecutar la instrucción de pintado ante del sleep()?.

Si esto tiene solución por favor estoy atento en la caja de respuestas, pero quizás me estoy complicando y hay alguna forma mas sencilla de resolverlo.

Muchas gracias por leer.

Comment: aunque no me gusta el uso de sleep puedes forzar el pintado usado `QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()` antes de sleep.

Comment: Amigo mil gracias, no sabes del lío del que me has sacado.